# Getting more than 1000 objects using SharpGs library

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-storage

I have many 1000s of files in Google Cloud Storage and I'm writing a .Net application to process the list of files. I'm using the SharpGs .Net library (https://github.com/acropolium/SharpGs) which seems simple and easy enough to use. However, I only seem to be getting back 1000 objects.

I am using the following code:

```
var bucket = GoogleStorageClient.GetBucket(rootBucketName)
var objects = bucket.Objects;
```

There doesn't seem to be any obvious way to obtain the next 1000 objects so I'm a bit stuck at the moment.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this particular library, but 1000 objects is the current limit for a single list call. Beyond that, you'd need to use paging to access the rest of the objects. If this library has support for paging, I'd recommend using that.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Bucket class:

https://github.com/acropolium/SharpGs/blob/master/SharpGs/Internal/Bucket.cs#L33

It returns a Query object. The Query object allows you to pass in a Marker parameter:

https://github.com/acropolium/SharpGs/blob/master/SharpGs/Internal/Query.cs#L36

You will have to take the initial Query object, extract its marker, then pass it to a new Query to get the next page of results.

Comment: I did notice the WithMarker() method but wasn't sure where or how to get the market that this method requires. I tried the etag property but this didn't work. Any ideas on where it comes from?